# OnAppear does not update State, button action does

Tags: swift, state, onappear

In a `ContentView()`, I have a the below:

```swift
@State var entries = [AType]()

var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                if self.entries.count == 0 {
                    Button {
                        loadChartData()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Load data")
                    }

                } else {
                    Section {
                        ChartView(entries: self.entries).frame(height: 150).padding()
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("My Title")
            .onAppear {
                loadChartData()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func loadChartData() {
        MyController.shared.fetchEntries { result in
            switch result {
                case .success(let entries):
                    self.entries = entries.data
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The button action works, and modifies the state appropriately, showing the ChartView, however the `onAppear` part doesn't. I've tried putting this in a `Dispatch.main.async()` call, and also used `.task {}` instead of `.onAppear{}`, but nothing seems to make any difference.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If it's in `ContentView`, why do you need it to be triggered on appear? Can you please provide some context on what is it that you're trying to achieve? Maybe there's a better way of implementing it.

Comment: Why does it matter if its in `ContentView`?
I'd like to fetch data (`fetchEntries`) and provide that to the `ChartView`, whenever the user loads this view.

Comment: Since `ContentView` is the first view to load?

Comment: I don't understand, how does that affect whether the function in `onAppear` is able to change state or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using `@Published` on a instance variable in the `MyController` class, and then using a `@ObservedObject` variable in the ContentView struct. Lastly, a function is called by `onAppear` in `ContentView` that updates the `@Published` variable in the controller, which then re-renders the `ContentView`.